# Disabling Overlapped Recycling in IIS 6.0

Tags: iis

I can't seem to find information on how to disable overlapped application pool recycling in IIS. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command should be:

```
cd \inetpub\adminscripts
adsutil SET w3svc/AppPools/DisallowOverlappingRotation "1"
```

Or, you can set it for a specific app pool with

```
adsutil SET w3svc/AppPools/AppPoolName/DisallowOverlappingRotation "1"
```

Be sure to replace "AppPoolName" with your app pool name.

I didn't test it, I typed it based on looking at the metabase, but it's going to be something very similar. If my first guess didn't work, let me know and I'll update it.

I'm curious why you want to set this.  When are the overlapping app pools an issue?

Comment: The service in question requires exclusive access to TIBRV ledger files. With overlapped recycling we occasionally see errors if the second app pool process starts up prior to the first completely shutting down.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Sounds like a fairly unique requirement, but a valid reason to disable the overlapping.

Comment: Certainly an uncommon situation. My scenario, a db4o database. I wonder if the same happens with the new in process sql express. Was hoping for a .config setting :(.

Answer (score 0):

I have just set this up (thanks to the previous answer for finding the right key) - it is not settable on individual app pools in IIS6, but must be set for them all:

AdsUtil //NoLogo set "w3svc/AppPools/DisallowOverlappingRotation" "1"

In IIS 7 it is settable for each app pool, and can be done in the GUI or using the Powershell IIS provider:

$recycling = Get-ItemProperty "iis:\apppools\${appPool}" -name "Recycling";
$recycling.disallowOverlappingRotation = $True;
Set-ItemProperty "iis:\apppools\${appPool}" -name "Recycling" -value $recycling;

Comment: -1 It is settable per application pool in IIS 6, as confirmed in the [IIS Documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/ec26f50e-dcc9-4439-acc1-d7d8cff8e0ee.mspx?mfr=true).